# Is there a definition of "up to" where "up to 100% protection" is a meaningful statement?

Tags: meaning

OK, so I'm a math geek, and I realize that sometimes I interpret the world, uh, *differently*.  For example, I see a package advertising that the contents were made with "real fruit", and I show it to my sister, "Look! It's not made with imaginary fruit!" (This is related to, but not quite the same phenomenon as, answering "would you like milk or lemon in your tea" with "yes".)

When a few years ago certain feminine products began to advertise themselves as offering "up to [insert number here] hours protection", naturally I translated that to "less than [number] hours protection", and all was right in my world. It's a meaningless advertising *claim*, but it's not, in and of itself, a meaningless *statement*: it just means something quite different than they're trying to imply. (Namely, if the "up to 8 hours protection" product fails after 5 minutes, the product has perfectly satisfied the claim. If the product fails after 8 and a half hours, *then* the customer would have a valid complaint about the product not working as advertised.)

But then the advertising departments came up with a new twist: the "up to zero leaks" guarantee, also seen as "up to 100% protection". Wait, what? I mean, all logic aside, I can see how someone could see "protects for up to 10 hours" as a stronger claim than "protects for up to 8 hours", so it makes sense for advertising departments to come up with such meaningless claims. But "up to 100% of the whole"?!? That's... completely devoid of any meaning. How, exactly, am I supposed to interpret such a claim?

Comment: This seems to be a math question. I assume you know what the advertisers mean.

Comment: As a math geek, you should be able to decide whether the statements you describe are meaningful.

Comment: That’s the beauty of this in an advertisement-  it means nothing but people will see the words ***”100% protection”*** when they glance at it.

Comment: More of a legal question than a maths one. You could ask again on Law SE.  Needs a little rephrasing. Ask if "up to" has a legal meaning in advertising.  Ask if  "up to 8 hours" that fails in 5 minutes is false advertising.

Comment: If something is advertised as providing or being ***Up to N***, that means *up to **and including** N*. No amount of "autistic literalism" can plausibly justify interpreting it as *up to **but not including** N*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, that's not at all what the question is asking. It's asking, what information is conveyed by a statement that logically conveys absolutely nothing? It's like answering "Is the light on?" with "The light is currently either on or off."

Comment: @JPmiaou: OP's text ends *How, exactly, am I supposed to interpret such a claim?* Which to my mind is equivalent to *What does that claim **mean**?*  You (and perhaps the OP, I dunno) seem to mistakenly believe noun phrases like *up to 100% protection* don't mean anything. Either that, or OP is *really* asking ***Why** would someone make such a claim?*, which is beyond the remit of this site.

Comment: (Obviously the response in your "light" example is "inappropriate". But OP's context doesn't involve any "question" inappropriately answered, so that's irrelevant.)

Comment: OK, fine, it's like _saying_ "the light is either on or off". The only information that conveys is that the light exists. "Up to 100% effective" is logically equivalent to "either effective or ineffective", which doesn't tell us anything: everything is either effective or not. So what information are those words _supposed_ to convey? What do those words mean?